# Confusion on events being dependent or independent (in an example).

Tags: probability, independence

**Background:** I have learnt that if events are disjoint they must be dependent. 

I am stuck with this example answer that I have found, here it is:

> In every round of a game, $n$ players throw a legit coin (half probability for head and half for tails.), independently. if one of the players gets a different result from all the other players, he gets out of the game, else they start a new round again, the game keeps going until there's 2 players left which are the winners. 
> Q: For a general $n$, what are the expected value, variance and sd of number of rounds that will take place.

Now, I was looking at the answer and here's what they did : 
We define $Y_k$ as number of rounds that took place while there was $k$ players, until someone gets out. 
**And here's my confusion:** 
They said that any set of games is independent with the other sets of games (since their intersection is empty), specially for $Y_3, Y_4,...,Y_{n}$. 
**My Question**: Since the intersection is empty, the sets are disjoint, and that means they're dependent, so why are they using that to say the sets are independent, what am I missing?

Comment: Which events are you claiming have empty intersection?

Comment: @MichaelHardy It's what was written in the start of the answer of the example, they are talking about the sets of games $Y_3, Y_4, Y_5, ... , Y_n$, like the number of rounds each one of these sets had, I'm not sure if I understood it correctly here, but I'm confused about the explanation of the sets of games being independent based on their intersection being empty (which was an explanation in the answer to the example)

Comment: It looks to me as if you're confusing intersection of _events_, in the sense in which that term is used in probability theory, with intersection of sets of random variables.

Comment: @MichaelHardy That's probably my problem right here, could you please emphasize on the difference, and why if the intersection of sets of random variables is empty then they are independent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two sets $\{Y_1,Y_2\}$ and $\{Y_2,Y_3\}$ are not disjoint.

The sets $\{Y_1\}$ and $\{Y_2\}$ are disjoint. And the two random variables $Y_1,Y_2$ are independent.

We have four possible outcomes:

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
Y_1 = 1 & \text{and } & Y_2 = 1 \\[6pt]
Y_1 = 1 & \text{and } & Y_2 = 0 \\[6pt]
Y_1 = 0 & \text{and } & Y_2 = 1 \\[6pt]
Y_1 = 0 & \text{and } & Y_2 = 0 
\end{array}
$$
The two events $\big[ Y_1=1\big]$ and $\big[ Y_2=1 \big]$ are not disjoint since they can both happen, and do both happen when the outcome is $\big[ Y_1=1\text{ and } Y_2=1\big].$ And they are independent.

An **event** is a set of outomes. Above, four outcomes are listed. As a *set* of outcomes, the event $\big[ Y_1=1\big]$ is the set whose members are the first two of the four listed outcomes, and the event $\big[Y_2=1\big]$ is the set whose members are the first and third of the listed outcomes. Those two events are independent of each other. They are not disjoint since they have one member in common, namely the first of the four listed outcomes.

Contrast this with the fact that the two random variables $Y_1+Y_2$ and $Y_2+Y_3$ are *not* independent precisely because the two sets $\{Y_1,Y_2\}$ and $\{Y_2,Y_3\}$ are not disjoint.

Events, i.e. sets of outcomes, cannot be independent if they are disjoint (except when the probability of at least one of them is $0$). Sets of random variables are another matter.

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation! I've got some questions if possible, the first one about the four possibilities, I didn't quite get why we have only these four outcomes, since each $Y_k$ can keep going until someone gets a coin flip different than all. (So I just took it as an example for the explanation, just making sure I'm not missing something).    My second question is in general, how do I read a random variable set? for example the set $\{ Y_1 \}$, all I'm thinking about is $\{0,1 \}$ aka all the possible outcomes of $Y_1$, but that makes $\{ Y_1 \}, \{ Y_2 \}$ not disjoint so I guess

Comment: I'm reading it wrong. And the last thing I wanted to ask is why does random variable disjoint sets mean independency, is there any theorem or definition I can look up to read about it?

Comment: @Pwaol : Disjointness of the sets of random variables implies they are independent only because it was given at the outset that all of the random variables involved are mutually independent.